# Redirect all traffic from http://example.com to http://www.example.com at the DNS level

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon Web Services to host my site and since I am going to use the ELB service I will need to redirect all my traffic from http://example.com to http://www.example.com.

Is this possible through the DNS?

I am using Route 53 as my DNS. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Given the protocol identifiers in your URLs, you can already see that it is impossible. You want two completely unrelated protocols in ways they have not been designed for ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot do redirects in DNS.

Instead, you need an HTTP server that sends HTTP 301 redirects in response to requests for `mysite.com`.
Most registrars offer redirect servers; consult yours.

Comment: Indeed my registrar offers a free redirect service. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Even quicker than organicveggie that doesn't require `mod_rewrite` (but what fun is it running Apache without mod_rewrite?) is that you can just redirect directly from your site config. This requires no webroot to be created at all. This should go within your `<VirtualHost *:80>` section for this site:

```
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias *.mydomain.* myotherdomain.* *.myotherdomain.* yetanotherdomain.*
Redirect 301 / http://mymaindomain.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

To supplement SLaks response, a common way to handle this is to use mod_rewrite in Apache and send a 301 redirect. In other words, let ELB send the traffic to an Apache server running on your EC2 instance. Then have Apache send a redirect if the hostname does not include www.

Here's a sample snippet:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http:/www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Hope that helps.